# Swift Combine sink returns demand .none

Tags: swift, combine, objectbox

I have the following code to listen to an ObjectBox query:

```
query.publisher
     .mapError(DatabaseError.other(nested:))
     .eraseToAnyPublisher()
     .map(mapEntities(_:))
     .catch(handleError) // Returns Empty<[..], Never> but also tried Just<[...]>
     .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
     .sink { results in
         self.allEntities = results
     })
```

- I have the `eraseToAnyPublisher` part because up until that part the code is in on other function I removed for simplicity
- I save the returned cancellable

After the first values are received, I can see logs from object box that say `Unsubscribe`. I've checked the [source code](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-swift/blob/e94881e812c44db91cdf09da680a5509f7bfae61/Source/ios-framework/CommonSource/Combine.swift) and it seems like this happens when the subscriber returns demand `.none` but I can't figure out why this happens

Comment: Try adding a `.print` operator into your pipeline and moving it down stage by stage to determine which operator is changing the demand chain.  At a glance I would suspect the `catch` operator.

Comment: I've added a print after each stage but each one prints a 'request unlimited' then after the first value received, a 'received finished'. Based on your idea I've removed the catch and replaced `sink(receiveValue:)` with `sink(receiveCompletion:receiveValue:)` but the result is the same. Strangely enough, if I create a custom subscriber that requests unlimited values. It works as expected

Comment: If the request is unlimited at every step (as you would expect from `sink`) and the pipeline is sending a `finished` response, the I would say the problem lies with `ObjectBox` and the query you've given it.  I don't have any expertise that particular library, but it seems that the Combine pieces are doing what they are supposed to.